Reduce 2d array of change history to initial and final values per id and remove rows where no change
There is an array of "movements" of elements, about the same, only it can be many times more:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90415
            [oldDate] => 2024-08-27
            [newDate] => 2024-08-28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90415
            [oldDate] => 2024-08-28
            [newDate] => 2024-08-27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90409
            [oldDate] => 2024-08-21
            [newDate] => 2024-08-22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90409
            [oldDate] => 2024-08-22
            [newDate] => 2024-08-23
        )
)

I'm trying to make sure that all the intermediate movements of the element are deleted, only the initial and final ones remain, and the elements of the array are deleted, where the element is returned to its original position (0 and 1 elements of the array). In the end, the processed array should look like this:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90409
            [oldDate] => 2024-08-21
            [newDate] => 2024-08-23
        )
)

how can I do this so that an array of a large number of elements does not delay the script for a long time

The processed array will then be sent to a separate method that will continue to work with it. I tried to do it, but I can't figure it out:

How to understand that the newDate element has the last one, and delete all other elements, leaving 2 values, and you need to go through all the elements of the array, do you need to make a regular expression?
How to delete only elements with opposite oldDate and newDate, while leaving others with the same ID


what are you ultimately doing with the processed array? I am asking because you could think about passing the array to a message queue to process it asynchronously if you don't need to return it to somewhere in the current request. That way, it will not delay the script execution.

Here is a solution that uses an intermediate $data associative array, which allows efficient lookups:
$moves = [
    ['id' => 90415, 'oldDate' => '2024-08-27', 'newDate' => '2024-08-28'],
    ['id' => 90415, 'oldDate' => '2024-08-28', 'newDate' => '2024-08-27'],
    ['id' => 90409, 'oldDate' => '2024-08-21', 'newDate' => '2024-08-22'],
    ['id' => 90409, 'oldDate' => '2024-08-22', 'newDate' => '2024-08-23'],
    ];

$data = [];
foreach($moves as $move)
{
    $id = $move['id'];
    if(isset($data[$id]))
    {
        // Id already present, update its newDate
        $data[$id]['newDate'] = $move['newDate'];
    }
    else
    {
        // New id, store it
        $data[$id] = $move;
    }
}

// Keep ids with different oldDate and newDate
$result = array_filter($data, fn($move) => $move['oldDate'] != $move['newDate']);

// Remove array keys
$result = array_values($result);

var_export($result);

Output:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 90409,
    'oldDate' => '2024-08-21',
    'newDate' => '2024-08-23',
  ),
)


Simply for comparison, here is the functional-style equivalent of Olivier's (flawless) solution. Demo
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_filter(
            array_reduce(
                $movements,
                function($carry, $move) {
                    $carry[$move['id']] ??= $move;
                    $carry[$move['id']]['newDate'] = $move['newDate'];
                    return $carry;
                }
            ),
            fn($move) => $move['oldDate'] != $move['newDate']
        )
    )
);

It could also be written as: Demo
$grouped = [];
foreach ($movements as $move) {
    $grouped[$move['id']] ??= $move;                     // store if a new id
    $grouped[$move['id']]['newDate'] = $move['newDate']; // overwrite stored newDate
}

var_export(
    array_values(
        array_filter(
            $grouped,
            fn($move) => $move['oldDate'] != $move['newDate']
        )
    )
);

